# Webpack babel returns only development big files > 250kb

Tags: webpack

I try many ways and no one doesn't work.
I set node env, force env, and always I had big js file

How get production mode and compressed, optimized javascript?
...............................................................
..............................................................

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    entry: {
        main: ["@babel/polyfill/noConflict", "./js/index.js"],
        
    },
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/env"],
                    },
                },
            },
            
            
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    
    
};
```

packge.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development"
  },
```

Comment: Which development only files are included?

Comment: @chenxsan no one